# Session Time out modal hides behind the already opened Dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

This is Angular4 with Bootstrap4 application, I have session timeout Modal which works fine if another modal is open (it displays on top of the second modal) but the issue is if a dialog box is open, session timeout modal is displayed behind the dialog box. I have already set the z-index of session timeout modal to 99999 !important and the dialog box z-index to very less value, still the issue exists. I know this is CSS Styling issue? What else I missed? I want the Session timeout modal to display on top of the Dialog box

### Below is the code for the dialog box

```
<div class= "row">
    <dialog id="d1">            
    </dialog>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
 dialog#d1 {
            top:50px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 300px;
            z-index: 5;  
            position: fixed;      
        }
```

Below is the plunk code for sessionTimeout modal example, DialogService will invoke the session timeout modal when timeout is reached
[https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/4ey4Mn][1]

### Css set for Modal is

```
.custom-show {
    z-index: 99000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order for us to understand what is happening, please edit the question and include the (minimal) code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added sample code above.